# XmlSerializer differs between .NET 3.5 & CF.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, compact-framework

I've a library that turns under CF.NET & .NET but serialization differs between both. As a result, a XML file generated under CF.NET isn't readable under .NET, and that is a big problem for me !

Here the code sample :

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("config")]
public sealed class RemoteHost : IEquatable<RemoteHost>
{
    // ...
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        RemoteHost host = new RemoteHost("A");
        List<RemoteHost> hosts = new List<RemoteHost>();
        hosts.Add(host);
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RemoteHost>));
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, hosts);
    }
}
```

CF.NET xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <config Name="A">
  </config>
</ArrayOfConfig>
```

.NET xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<ArrayOfRemoteHost xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RemoteHost Name="A">
  </RemoteHost>
</ArrayOfRemoteHost>
```

How can I modify my program in order to generate the same XML ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug processing the root name, indeed. As a workaround: take control of the root manually:

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class MyRoot {
    [XmlElement("bar")]
    public List<RemoteHost> Hosts {get;set;}
}
```

This should serialize as

```
<foo><bar>...</bar>...</foo>
```

on either platform. Substitute `foo` and `bar` for your preferred names.

(personally, I'd be using binary output, though ;p)

Comment: Arghhhhhh... Doing this way I need to restructure all my business model... Binary output?

Comment: @Arnaud - just adding a wrapper at the point of serialization isn't really changing the whole model.